# Is there a way to turn a string into a function during runtime?

Tags: php

say I had this

```
$src = "function($message) { echo $message; }"
```

I'm looking for a way to turn the source as a string into an actual function during runtime, sorta like

```
$say_message = magic_command($src);
$say_message("hello");
```

but I haven't found a way to do it.

If you're pondering the purpose, I'm extracting data from a large string. To make it simpler to change the procedure, I created an intermediary language(regex really won't do here) which I'm just eval'ing right now. I figured turning the procedure into a php native function might speed up the processing.. worth a shot. Security is not a concern, I'm the only one using this.

Comment: `eval()` would the function you are looking for: http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Comment: doh, didn't think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$src = '$say_message = function($message) { echo $message; };';
eval($src);
$say_message("hello");
```

This is the actual way to get $say_message to work as a function through string, you have to use `eval()`, make sure you add the proper `;` in the code

There is also another way to create it but not from a single string, using `create_function()`

```
$say_message = create_function('$message','echo $message;');
$say_message("hello");
```